# Generic CRUD in Entity Framework using a entity not specified

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, generics

I'm trying to make a Generic CRUD for my project. However I used DataBaseFirst and I do not see how to have a generic Entity class that can be inherited. Well it does not make the slightest sense, eventually when I upgrade the bank, it would have to go into all the more than 60 classes of the tables and add the inheritance again. I want the entity classes that the Entity Framawork generated pure, such as were generated.

So I'm trying something like:

```
public class DaoEF<TEntity> : IDaoEF<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    public GPSdEntities _dbContext { get; set; } = new GPSdEntities();


    public async Task<TEntity> GetById(int id)
    {
        return await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>()
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);
    }
```

But as you can deduce I have this problem about the property not being defined, since as I said, I do not want to have anything like a "General Entity".

Does anyone know of any way I can do this? Maybe it has some class that Entity uses by default that can be used in the where restriction. Or maybe if instead of Generics I used Reflection? Any idea?

Comment: You maybe could do ``((dynamic)e).Id == id``

Comment: Or use the `Find` method: `_dbContext.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().Find(id)` (if it works with AsNoTracking...)

Comment: So thanks for you answers RandRandom and DavidG!!! It's solve my problem.

Comment: @DavidG I still do not know if this solves all my problems, but let's try. And instead of AsNoTracking I can use Async method, like this: return await DbContexto.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(Key);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching I found this article in Portuguese: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn630213.aspx

using this generic methods in generic class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Repositorio.DAL.Contexto;
namespace Repositorio.DAL.Repositorios.Base
{
public abstract class Repositorio<TEntity> : IDisposable,
   IRepositorio<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    BancoContexto ctx = new BancoContexto();
    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return ctx.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> Get(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
    {
        return GetAll().Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
    }

    public TEntity Find(params object[] key)
    {
        return ctx.Set<TEntity>().Find(key);
    }

    public void Atualizar(TEntity obj)
    {
        ctx.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void SalvarTodos()
    {
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Adicionar(TEntity obj)
    {
        ctx.Set<TEntity>().Add(obj);
    }

    public void Excluir(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
    {
        ctx.Set<TEntity>()
            .Where(predicate).ToList()
            .ForEach(del => ctx.Set<TEntity>().Remove(del));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ctx.Dispose();
    }
}
```

}